# How to summary the multiple entry into a single sheet by name and by date?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

Names are in rows and Dates are in columns.

Sheet 1:

```
Name 1-Jun-18 2-Jun-18 3-Jun-18.......
KB    CL               
KB              EL
AJ                       SL
SD    SL
SD              CL
```

I need this data to be like below table in Sheet 2:

```
Name 1-Jun-18 2-Jun-18 3-Jun-18.......
KB    CL        EL   
AJ                       SL
SD    SL        CL
```

I need to fetch and create a summary dashboard/month view report.

Answer (score 1):

**cell A2: `=UNIQUE('Sheet1'!A2:A6)`**

**cell B1: `=QUERY('Sheet1'!B1:D1)`**

**cell B2: `=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER({'Sheet1'!B$2:B$6};{'Sheet1'!B$2:B$6}<>""; 
                 ('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$6)=$A2);1);)`** **and drag it to the right and down**

[image]